# What is the difference between deserving something and being entitled to something?

Tags: ethics

Some more questions to ask:

• What does a two-year-old deserve? What is this two-year-old entitled to?

• What does a two-year-old with a severe physical or mental disorder deserve? What are they entitled to? How is this different from what a perfectly healthy two-year-old deserves/is entitled to?

• What does a criminal deserve? What is a criminal entitled to?

• Is having the right to something completely different from being entitled to or deserving something?

• What factors go into deciding what a person deserves and what they're entitled to?

I want to have an in-depth discussion about this.
Thanks in advance to anyone who sees this and decides to discuss it with me!

Comment: First off, welcome to philosophy.SE. This site is not primarily about "in-depth discussion." Instead, we're here to answer questions about philosophy that you might have

Comment: Oh, alright. I apologize, then, and thank you for informing me!

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your specific question about the distinction between "deserving" and "being entitled", I think the basic answer is that this is not a philosophical distinction. Or to reword that, I've not seen "being entitled" used in the philosophical literature on ethics. For that matter, "deserve" only shows up in rare contexts.

Instead, we speak of "rights". If we are going to find a philosophical distinction, I would say it's this:

*Deserving* would be a term that reflects what one has a natural right to. In other words, that which one's worth implies one should receive.

*Entitled to* would be a term that reflects what one can or could legally force others to provide. Here, the key is that one has a "title" - a formal positive right.

But again, here I'm stretching a bit and just answering based on the distinction I see in English language usage and connecting that to an issue in philosophy. If you mean different things, then it doesn't work.

For views where natural rights don't exist, the distinction fully collapses since the only rights are the positive rights granted in law.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the difference is a matter of the context where the term appears. I think of entitlement as a legal question. You would do your legal research to decide whether someone owed you a duty to deliver a parcel of land, for example. I see the idea of deserving something as some claim on the general community: personal respect, for example.

I think of the boundaries of what you deserve as much less certain than that what you are entitled to.